# Remove the same element in element set

Tags: jquery, arrays

In my case, I have select some elements base on $('a,form,[onclick]'), however, since there some elements are contain onclick attribute, it will be got twice. I want to remove the same element object from this element set. What I do is use codes below, however, it doesn't work:

```
total = $('a,form,[onclick]')
$(total).each(function(index, element) {
         for(var i=index;i<total.length;i++){
        if($(this)[0] == $(total[i])[0]){
            $(total[i]).remove();
        }
    }
});
```

How should I solve this problem, please help, thanks

Comment: Forget about `onclick`, is the best you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [unique](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/) function:

```
$.unique(total);
```

Comment: thank you mck, unique works, and should use $('a,form,[onclick]').get(), or it doesn't work